# Test Intel Low Precision Optimization Tool using dummy dataset

Tags: tensorflow2.0, intel, intel-lpot

I was trying out Intel Low Precision Optimization Tool in Linux. Initially I have created one environment named lpot_environment and installed tensorflow using the below command:

```
conda create -n lpot_environment python=3.7
pip install intel-tensorflow==2.3.0
```

Then I cloned the github repository as :

```
git clone https://github.com/intel/neural-compressor.git
```

I have the frozen model downloaded.

As an initial step toward intel lpot, I would like to run with a dummy dataloader. But I failed to find one.

It would be great if anybody send a code sample using dummy dataset in intel lpot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to quantize a TensorFlow checkpoint and run with a dummy dataloader.

```
quantizer = Quantization('./conf.yaml')
dataset = quantizer.dataset('dummy_v2', \
    input_shape=(100, 100, 3), label_shape=(1, ))
quantizer.model = common.Model('./model/public/rfcn-resnet101-coco-tf/rfcn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28/')
quantizer.calib_dataloader = common.DataLoader(dataset)
quantized_model = quantizer()
```

Run quantization will create a dummy dataloader.

Comment: In conf.yaml, dataset is needed to be specified. What we have to enter in that field?

Comment: dataset:

        ImageRecord:
          root: /path/to/imagenet/

Comment: In this case no need to specify  dataset in conf.yaml.